# Is there a way to approve a rejected edit on my own question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I've got a message that there is a [pending edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/73783) for my question [How to find a secret case within a case?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157164/how-to-find-a-secret-case-within-a-case). By the time I saw the message and went to review the edit, it already got rejected by two users. However, the edit is valid and adds good information to the question. This edit was done by an anonymous user, but theoretically, If this happens with a non anonymous user, is there a way to accept an edit after it was rejected so that the editing user would get the appropriate credit?

I will add the data from that edit to the question anyway, just wanted to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: I can't speak for @kalina, but I rejected the edit because it looked like it was a comment or (attempted) answer, and not a clarification to the question.  _There is no previous mention of paperclips_ in the question, and the paperclip in the screenshot is non-obvious.

Comment: @MBraedley, I realize that it looks like an attempted answer through an edit, I may have rejected it as well if I didn't play the game myself, and my guess was that this is the reason it got rejected. Also, while it adds correct information, it still needs edit to put it in the correct context, so that even people who didn't play the game will understand them. But i assure you that it's a valid edit, what it actually provides is the list of missions that have secret cases.

Comment: But it's still an invalid edit.  It's not a clear edit.  _As worded_, it really doesn't add any clarification to the post.  The edit needs to be more explicit.  I wouldn't have rejected something like "The missions that have secret cases are...", which is what the edit tries to do **but doesn't**.  As I've said before, I don't need to know the answer to a question, but I do need to understand what's being asked.  It's similar for edits.  I need to understand what the edit is adding for me to approve it.  If you really want the extra clarification, add it in yourself.  But make it clear.

Comment: @MBraedley, this is exactly where the button "improve" comes in handy. The problem is I can't do this because the edit was rejected.

Comment: The edit comes from an anonymous user. We can't give credit even if we wanted to.

Comment: You're not really hearing me.  The edit was unclear to me, so how am I supposed to improve it?  Additionally, it didn't look like a valid edit (because it isn't one), so I rejected it.  If I knew more about the game, then maybe I would have seen the nugget of value in it, but unfortunately, that didn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: you'll have to apply the edit by hand. It's easier if you switch the view from rendered output to markdown.

If you want to give credit, simply link to the edit author's profile page.

Comment: @vaishali Well, the asker asked about the case when the edit came from an actual user.